# Dynamically evaluate XPath stored in a variable

Tags: xml, xpath, orbeon, xforms, xbl

I have a variable:

```
<xf:var name="xpath" value="/my/xpath/expression"/>
```

and I want to use `/my/xpath/expression` in the `ref` attribute of `<xf:input>`:

```
<xf:input ref="/my/xpath/expression"/>
```

Here I use a hardcoded XPath expression, but I want instead to use the XPath expression stored in the `$xpath` variable instead, something like this :

```
<xf:input ref="$xpath"/>
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `<xf:input ref="{$xpath}" />`? Or do you want a string literal? Then try: `<xf:var name="xpath" value="'/my/xpath/expression'" />`

Comment: First solution is not working: unexpected token '{' in xpath expresion. Second solution, as I mentioned in my post, determine to hardcode xpath, but I have xpath in variable $xpath ($xpath="/my/xpath/expression")

Comment: Or is it `<xf:variable name="xpath" select="/my/xpath/expression" />`? Also have a look at the binding parameter, may that one accepts variables.

Comment: @CoDEmanX, thanks for the suggestions on this one. I provided an answer below. AVTs are not supported on XForms attributes which are *already* XPath expressions, such as `ref`. Also, `<xf:variable select="…">` was supported but XForms 2.0 standardizes on `<xf:var value="…">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably mean is that the value of `$xpath` is a string, literal or not, which you then want to evaluate. It's different to say:

```
<xf:var name="xpath" value="/my/xpath/expression"/>
```

and:

```
<xf:var name="xpath" value="'/my/xpath/expression'"/>
```

In the first case, the variable `$xpath` contains an XPath expression which is evaluated when the variable needs its value. The result will be an XPath type, such as a string, element, or in general any sequence of XPath items (`item()*`). If your expression is really say `/path/to/foo/bar`, then the result will a sequence of zero or more element nodes with name `bar`.

In the second case, notice the quotes `'`. This means that the value of `$xpath` is a *string*.

If you want then another XForms construct to do something with that string other than playing with it as a string, you will have to *evaluate* that expression dynamically.

There is a function for that, `saxon:evaluate()`. So you can write:

```
<xf:input ref="saxon:evaluate($xpath)"/>
```

You must make sure the `saxon` namespace prefix is in scope, with:

```
xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
```

There is a bit more to it, namely in what context the expression runs. In most cases, it should work.